# How can i use GNU Bash to find files of specific type without relaying on the file extension?

Tags: find, mime-types, mv

i have many pdf files without name extension dispersed in subdirectories. This prevents my bibliography software from organizing them. I want to identify these files, collect them on a new directory and, once there, add the missing .pdf extension.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

as stated in comments - you could use core linux tools - `find` and `file` commands. Following oneliner should work:

```
find your_starting_path -print0 |xargs -0 file |grep 'PDF document' > potential_pdfs.txt
```

Then you can verify your potential_pdfs.txt file, if all found files looks reasonable, and eventually clean up the file. Finally you may use this file as an input for cleanup script:

```
targetdirectory=some_path_for_pdfs
cat potential_pdfs.txt |awk -F: '{print $1}' | while read filename; do 
 base=$(basename "$filename")
 cp -v "$filename" "$targetdirectory/$base.pdf"
done
```

Eventually you may want to use mv to remove original files. Obiousely be careful with removing them. This script won't work for files containing `:` in names - for that you need to tweak it a bit.